# Convert jagged array to a list

Tags: c#, arrays, list, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

I have a jagged array which I want to convert to a simple list.

```
int[][] jaggedArray = new int[][] 
{
    new int[] {1,3,5,7,9},
    new int[] {0,2,4,6},
    new int[] {11,22}
};
```

I want to convert into a list

```
List<int> list = ?????
```

[Fast way to convert a two dimensional array to a List ( one dimensional )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132397/fast-way-to-convert-a-two-dimensional-array-to-a-list-one-dimensional)

This question converts a two dimensional array to a list but this fails for jagged array.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You might go with this:

```
List<int> list = jaggedArray.SelectMany(T => T).ToList();
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var list = jaggedArray.SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```