# Accessing one dimension of multidimensional array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array which looks like this:

```
public static int[,] GameObjects = new int[,]
{
    //Type,X,Y,Width,Height
    {0,50,50,10,100},
    {1,50,150,10,20}
};
```

I'm trying to access one "row" of values and store them into a variable within a `for` loop:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < gameObjectData.Length; i++)
 {
     int[] g = gameObjectData[i];
 }
```

I want g to store the first array's values, so in the first loop g should store `0,50,50,10,100`. The code gives the error `Wrong number of indices inside []; expected 2`

Comment: `int[,]` and `int[][]` are not the same. I forget the specifics (looking up now, I find it , I'll post an answer)

Comment: `int[,]` is not the same as `int[][]`. You need to copy the values of one row to a new array.

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132397/fast-way-to-convert-a-two-dimensional-array-to-a-list-one-dimensional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no exposed mechanism of a two dimensional array to get a single dimensional array out of it.

If you have a jagged array then it's possible:

```
int[][] array;
//populate array
int[] row = array[1];
```

If you need to have a multi-dimensional array then the best you could do is create a class to hold onto a two dimensional array and a row number and expose an indexer to access items in that row; it could appear similar to an array, but it wouldn't actually be one.

Something like this would give you the bare bones; if you wanted to make the type extend `IList<T>` you could do that as well.

```
public class ArrayRow<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private T[,] array;
    private int index;
    public ArrayRow(T[,] array, int index)
    {
        this.array = array;
        this.index = index;
    }

    public T this[int i]
    {
        get { return array[index, i]; }
        set { array[index, i] = value; }
    }

    public int Count { get { return array.GetLength(1); } }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
            yield return this[i];
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
public static ArrayRow<T> GetRow<T>(this T[,] array, int index)
{
    return new ArrayRow<T>(array, index);
}
```

Alternatively you could copy the value of each row in the multi-dimensional array to a new single dimensional array, but then neither will reflect changes made to the other.

Answer (score 3):

You get this error because you try to use a multidimensional array as if it was a jagged array.

Change

```
int[,]
```

to

```
int[][]
```

and you will be fine.
[Read here about the differences between these types of arrays.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-are-the-differences-between-a-multidimensional-array-and-an-array-of-arrays)

Answer (score 0):

For [multidimensional arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx) you need to access them like this:

```
// access 0,1
gameObjectData[0,1];

// access 5,4
gameObjectData[5,4];

// So in general is
gameObjectData[x,y];
```

You can't access it by just giving [x], so **for your question it would be**:

```
// asuming you want row 0
int row = 0;

// this give to g the size of the row of gameObjectData
int[] g = new int[gameObjectData.getLenght(row)];

for (int i = 0; i < gameObjectData.getLenght(row); i++)
{
   g[i] = gameObjectData[row,i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like one-liners, here is a LINQ one:

```
int rowIndex = 0;
firstRow = Enumerable.Range(0, gameObjectData.GetLength(1-rowIndex))
                     .Select(v => gameObjectData[rowIndex,v])
                     .ToArray();
```