# Convert multi-dimension array to string

Tags: c#, arrays, char

I have a 3 dimensional char array initialized as such:

`char[,,] cube = new char[10, 10, 10];`

It's completely filled and I want to convert its contents to a single string. My current method is this:

```
for (int z = 0; z < 10; z++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
            build += cube[z, y, x];
        }
    }
}
```

Attempting to do `build = new string(cube)` gives an error:
`cannot convert from 'char[*,*,*]' to 'char*'`

The `for` loops are incredibly fast, completing in less than a millisecond on my setup (from 1500 to 4000 ticks). Wondering if a single line method exists that will accomplish the same thing that these nested `for` loops are doing?

**EDIT:**
This code will only be used once in the entire program, so I don't need something reusable.

Comment: Simple create an extension method and it will be single line

Comment: you mean something like `var build = new string(cube.OfType<char>().ToArray());`?

Comment: Closest I could get: foreach (char s in cube) {build += s;}

Comment: @Corak, nice one!

Comment: Almost the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5132397/6400526). Read Jon's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ is your friend.

A multidimensional array implements `IEnumerable` but sadly apparently not `IEnumerable<T>`. So first we need to get an `IEnumerable<T>` to be able to make full use of LINQ. Luckily, we know in this case, that every item in that multidimensional array is of type`char`, we just need to tell that to the compiler.

Next, to create a `string`, there is a convenient constructor, that accepts a `char[]`. And getting a `char[]` from an `IEnumerable<char>` is just one `ToArray()` away.

Put that together and you get:

```
using System.Linq;

var build = new string(cube.OfType<char>().ToArray());
```

Comment: LINQ comes to the rescue again. This is perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is easier than you think:

```
public static String FlattenToString(this char[,,] array)
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder();

    foreach(var @char in array)
    {
        builder.Append(@char);
    }

    return builder.ToString();
}

var cube = new char[2,2,2];

cube[0,0,0] = 'a';
cube[0,0,1] = 'b';
cube[0,1,0] = 'c';
cube[0,1,1] = 'd';
cube[1,0,0] = 'e';
cube[1,0,1] = 'f';
cube[1,1,0] = 'g';
cube[1,1,1] = 'h';

Console.WriteLine(cube.FlattenToString());
```

Prints out `abcdefgh`.

Comment: While the end result does do it in "one line", adding the Method here `FlattenToString` adds more lines than the nested loop does.

Answer (score 2):

```
string build = string.Concat(cube.Cast<char>());
```

---

Probably not needed in your case, but a much faster alternative is copying to `char[]` :

```
//var cube = new[, ,] { { { 'a', 'b' }, { 'c', 'd' } }, { { 'e', 'f' }, { 'g', 'h' } } };
char[] temp = new char[cube.Length];
Buffer.BlockCopy(cube, 0, temp, 0, temp.Length * sizeof(char));
string build = new string(temp);
```

Comment: @Corak true for earlier .NET versions. .NET 4 has `IEnumerable<T>` overload

Comment: sorry, I thought you were using `new string`, too. But you're actually using `string.Concat`, which *does* accept `IEnumerable<char>`.

Comment: About the performance... looks like`ToArray()` fills an internal Buffer, basically an array with starting size of 4, while `Concat` uses a `StringBuilder`, also basically an array but with starting size of 16. Both doubling the size when needed and doing `Array.Copy`, which is probably the most expensive operation in there. So `ToArray()` would have to do that two times more (4 => 8 => 16) -- then it really comes to the question, which one has more overhead. The Buffer keeps the `char` as `char`, while `Concat` does `ToString` on each char... that'd need very carefully done benchmarking.

Comment: `string.Concat(IEnumerable<T>)` uses a cached `StringBuilder` instance for up to 360 characters, but seems to be a bit slower on average for 1000 characters. My guess for the inconsistent results is mostly the branch mispredictions from the if statements. My tests with 1000 `char[,,]` are about 2 ms for the LINQ answers, about 10 ns with `new StringBuilder(cube.Length)` or unsafe `char*`, and only about 1 ns with `Buffer.BlockCopy` (~1000+ times faster than LINQ!)

Answer (score 1):

```
char[,,] cube = new char[10, 10, 10];
                for (int z = 0; z < 10; z++)
                {
                    for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
                    {
                        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
                        {
                            cube[z, y, x] = (char)(65+x);
                        }
                    }
                }
/* Just Filling data in array*/    
                var s1 = cube.OfType<char>().ToList();
                string s = string.Join("",s1);
```

Comment: You don't need explicit `ToList()`. `string.Join` works on `IEnumerable<string>`

Comment: @MrinalKamboj yeah thanx.